How to test $Q = CV$ for a parallel plate capacitor experimentally?
For educational purposes I want to test the formula $Q = CV$ for a parallel plate capacitor (like this) experimentally. My first idea was to use an electrometer amplifier (this one) to measure the charge $Q$. The problem is that this essentially works by using an STE capacitor and using the equation $Q = CV$ (compare manual page 6). So you run into a logical circularity.
If the capacitance wouldn't be so small I could measure the current time graph using for example Cassy and get the charge via integration.
I also tried the following: Charge the parallel plate capacitor with for example 10 volts, then watch the voltage by a quasi static voltmeter. I used also the electrometer amplifier without STE components for this. Then I carefully connected another identical parallel plate capacitor (same dimension and plate distance) to the first one and observed that the voltage drops to the half of the initial value. By symmetry I think it should be evident that the charge equally distributes over both capacitors ans such the charge on the first capacitor is reduced by a factor 1/2. One can do this multiple times. However this isn't very exact and you get only the proportionality, but since you doesn't measure the charge in coulombs you couldn't calculate $C$.
So how to do this experiment logically sound with good results?

I would use a different capacitor with higher capacitance, or introduce some dielectric within the plates to increase the capacitance a lot. Then you could determine the capacitance integrating for the transient current as you explained.

Just throwing an idea out there, but you could test it indirectly by implementing a switched-capacitor resistor.
The switched capacitor behaves as a resistor with $R = \frac{1}{fC}$ where $f$ is the switching frequency. So you could use a DC sourcemeter to verify the relationship.

@TobErnack: Is this the same as in this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/835605/6581 ?

@Julia Yes I think it is the same principle.

If you use a constant current source, the charge will be equal to the amperage times seconds ($\mathrm C =\mathrm A \cdot \text{sec}$ or $Q=I\times \Delta t$).
It then would be simple enough to measure the beginning and ending voltages, to compute capacitance.

Sounds good but the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor is very low thus the voltmeter has to have a very high resistance.

In principle yes. The problem is the order of magnitude. What would be your suggestion of how to choose the relevant values? Regarding the voltage measurement: If you measure with disconnected source, in practice only a static voltmeter or the electrometer amplifier linked in my post work.

A 30cm square, 1mm separation air capacitor has a capacitance of approximately one nanofarad. Thus you need a voltmeter whose resistance is if the order of one teraohm (time constant 1000 seconds). You then have the problem you mentioned in your question of a circular argument. However in the same way that you 'cheated' when verifying Newton's second law using hanging weights you can do the same with an electrometer?

THere in outline is the set up my students used for over forty years which I am sure can be adapted using more modern apparatus.

A parallel plate capacitor is charged, position A, and then discharged, position B, through a galvanometer 50 times a second and a 'steady' current recorder on the light spot galvanometer (Scalamp) using a $\rm1P2W$ (one pole two way) reed relay.
The capacitor consisted of two $\rm 30cm \times 30cm$ steel plates separated with 1cm $\times$ 1cm plastic spacers with a $\rm1kg$ mass on the top.
The separation of the plates could be increased by adding more spacers the thickness of which were measured using a micrometer and the overlap of the plates could be changed to change the area.
Thus $C\propto 1/d$ and $C\propto A$ could be investigated.
The plastic spacers were of the type which lined swimming pools and a $\rm 30cm \times 30cm$ sheet could be used to find the relative permittivity of the plastic.
A $\rm 10\,M\Omega$ resistor and dc voltage supply was used to calibrate the galvanometer.
——
Capacitor charge $Q=CV$ when connected to voltage source (position A) and the discharged through galvanometer (position B) at the frequency of the reed switch supply $f$.
Current reading on galvanometer $I= fQ = fCV$, from which the capacitance of the capacitor, $C$, can be found.

Thanks. This seems to be interesting. Could you add some more details about the theory, of how you get the capacity from the amp-reading exactly.

.
Your setup seems risky. If bigger capacitors were to be tested there is potential for damage to your galvanometer. They do not like high currents. The currents in that setup are limited by the voltage, and resistance of the meter, a few ohms. Plus there is no adjustment. I prefer volt meters, especially digital volt meters. They have input ohms of maybe 10 million.
If you are using a cyclic input voltage, a good oscilloscope would be preferred. What your circuit appears to be trying for is turning pulsed input to a average DC output through the meter. I'm not sure how that would be used to directly calculate Capacitance.
If you are stuck with the meter you have, consider putting a resistor, or variable resistor/potentiometer in series with the meter. And a current shunt parallel around both of them. I'm sorry I can't draw anything. You might also want to put a resistor in series with the voltage supply to slow the charging.
Start with a large resistance in series with the meter and a low shunt/parallel resistor around both the meter and series resistor. Slowly decrease the series, and then slowly increase the shunt, experiment cautiously. Amp meters are very easy to over current and destroy. You may already know or have learned that.
Volt meters are harder to over current, or over voltage.
.

Try to discharge the capacitor with a big resistor for 10 sec during which the voltage drop is around 5%-10%. Take the average of the voltages before and after the discharge, divide it by the resistance and multiply it by 10 sec. Now, you have the estimated charge removed from the capacitor.
